# How to get a function signature and declare another with the same signature using the preprocessor?

Tags: c

How can I get a function signature and declare another with the same signature using the preprocessor?

I wanted to do something like this:

```
int function_to_be_copied_from(int arg, int arg2);
FUNC_COPY_SIGNATURE(function_to_be_copied_from, new_function_name)
{
  do_something(arg, arg2);
}
```

And get this:

```
int function_to_be_copied_from(int arg, int arg2);
int new_function_name(int arg, int arg2)
{
  do_something(arg, arg2);
}
```

Gcc extensions are allowed, such as `typeof`, for example.

I want to create a runtime profiler system, specifically, I need to replace functions using a macro. This macro has got to create a wrapper function that computes the execution time of the replaced function and rename the replaced function.

Comment: Hmmm ... do you want, perhaps, `typedef` for the return type? `typedef double MyValueType; MyValueType fx1(); MyValueType fx2();` Changing the typedef changes the return value from all functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below approach:

Create a macro for profiling:

```
#define profile_me(my_code) ({timer_start_code; my_code timer_stop_code;})
// NOTE: there is no `;` after my_code in macro evaluation
// This helps for profiling any code, having braces. (see Sample_usage2)
// Sample_usage1: profile_me(function_to_be_copied_from(5,10););
// Sample_usage2: profile_me(if(condition){do_something();});
```

Create a recursive macro for the functions you want to profile:

```
#define function_to_be_copied_from(...) profile_me \
       (function_to_be_copied_from(__VA_ARGS__);)
```

Then use the original function normally. The profiling code will be called automatically.

For taking care of the return value:

```
#define profile_me_int(my_code) ({       \
    int ret;                             \
    timer_start_code;                    \
    ret = my_code                        \
    timer_stop_code;                     \
    ret;                                 \
}) // ret data type is chosen based on function_to_be_copied_from's return type

#define function_to_be_copied_from(...) profile_me_int \
       (function_to_be_copied_from(__VA_ARGS__);)
```

Comment: +1 Can you replace `int ret` with `typeof(my_code) ret`?